# Can Xamarin be used to run WPF on Mac and Mobile?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

This question is without exact details and is more theoretical.

From what I know, usual WPF apps can't be run on Mac. Since I am making a video game, it is important to me, because it leaves me without a big part of potential customers. I read that Xamarin has tools to make apps that will be usable on Mac. How can it be achieved?

I already installed Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin, but didn't have time to fully research its features.

What must be done, to make my game available on Mac? I guess that Xamarin won't just add something to exe file, to make it run on non-Windows system. So, what can be done? Is there something similar to WPF, but for Mac or Mobile? Some different kind of "template" that can use the majority, or even the whole existing code?

I don't ask to be fully guided through the process, if there is available information on the internet, giving the link will be enough.

Thank you,
Evgenie

Comment: Xcode would be your go-to for Mac desktop development I believe, I haven't had chance to flick through the UI libraries for it though so I may be wrong.

Comment: Short answer, no

Comment: Don't forget you need .NET Framework and .NET Runtime to run WPF or any other Windows apps on Mac. Why would you go to Mac? it's like switching to the dark side of the force?

Comment: you use WPF to make games?

Comment: Jason: Yes, I am now making a game with wpf. XAMINAX: I want to keep using Visual Studio on Windows, but make end product availble on Mac.

Comment: I consider Mac for development to be a `peasant land`, if you want to have a good looking apps Windows is your answer here. When it comes to WPF and games, don't, the overhead with all the objects is too much to have a smooth frame rate. But if you want to have cross-platform game look into Unity 3D it will make it available to mobiles as well.

Comment: I was thinking about Unity 3d, but I don't know what is easier - to convert my code to Unity or to Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Unity is guaranteed to have support and to show you how to code a game, with xamarin forms you create desktop apps, which won't be teaching you how to keep your game to be responsive. I am surprised you would even consider xamarin forms for that. BTW you need to use `@` symbol in your comments otherwise I won't get notification, like @EvgenieT but @XAMlMAX

Comment: @XAMlMAX Okay, thank you for suggesting Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can Xamarin be used to run WPF on Mac and Mobile?

No. WPF applications runs on Windows only. Period.

You can use Xamarin.Forms to build native user interfaces for iOS, Android and Windows using C# and XAML but that's not the same thing as WPF: https://www.xamarin.com/forms

Comment: That's what I am asking - is there something suitable for Mac, but with similar structure? EDIT: Xamarin.Forms - doesn't it have limitation like Windows Forms?

Comment: Something like WPF for Mac? No. The closest you get is Xamarin.Forms. I don't know what you mean by "limitation". I guess all frameworks have their limitations. But if you follow the link you can read more about Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Okay, that's the answer I hoped for - you provided a tool that can be replace WPF. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Xamarin Forms as a library for cross-platform development.

Means that you have a shared codebase (view / viewmodels / model) and so on.
But you would still need to go through the native system (e.g. Mac, Windows, Android) to implement all the view components the right way.

As you can see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1) xamarin forms will sooner or later support WPF and MacOS Projects so you can programm you WPF application and use the shared codebase.

But I would don't recommend you to use wpf to develop your game.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: **NO**
Xamarin is just a platform to create platform independent mobile apps for windows, iOS & android.

Comment: What I was asking for, is to recommend something that can be used instead of WPF, that works on Mac, and won't require too many changes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to make?

Comment: Don't worry, I got an answer from another person.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Unity 3D engine, which allows you to create games which are cross-platform and also available through Web Browser! [Link to Unity](https://unity3d.com/)